# cpp version "end of search list"

Tags: 16.04, compiler

When i checked the **cpp** version it showed me this message:

```
cpp -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=cpp
OFFLOAD_TARGET_NAMES=nvptx-none
OFFLOAD_TARGET_DEFAULT=1
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../src/configure -v --with-pkgversion='Ubuntu
7.3.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.york1' --with-bugurl=file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-  
7/README.Bugs --enable-languages=c,ada,c++,go,brig,d,fortran,objc,obj-c++  
--prefix=/usr --with-gcc-major-version-only --program-suffix=-7 --program-
prefix=x86_64-linux-gnu- --enable-shared --enable-linker-build-id 
--libexecdir=/usr/lib --without-included-gettext --enable-threads=posix 
--libdir=/usr/lib --enable-nls --with-sysroot=/ --enable-clocale=gnu 
--enable-libstdcxx-debug --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --with-default-
libstdcxx-abi=new --enable-gnu-unique-object --disable-vtable-verify 
--enable-libmpx --enable-plugin --with-system-zlib --with-target-system-
zlib --enable-objc-gc=auto --enable-multiarch --disable-werror --with-
arch-32=i686 --with-abi=m64 --with-multilib-list=m32,m64,mx32 --enable-
multilib --with-tune=generic --enable-offload-targets=nvptx-none 
--without-cuda-driver --enable-checking=release --build=x86_64-linux-gnu 
--host=x86_64-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-1ubuntu1~16.04.york1) 
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/cc1 -E -quiet -v -imultiarch x86_64-linux-  
gnu - -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -
Wformat-security
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include/x86_64-linux-gnu"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/include-    
fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../..   
/../x86_64-linux-gnu/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
/usr/local/include
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/include
End of search list.
```

Is this message an error or a warning?, What can i do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is neither an error nor a warning - it is the *verbose* output, including the pre-processor search path. From `man cpp`:

```
   -v  Verbose mode.  Print out GNU CPP's version number at the beginning
       of execution, and report the final form of the include path.
```

If you want only the version information, you can use `cpp --version`:

```
   -version
   --version
       Print out GNU CPP's version number.  With one dash, proceed to
       preprocess as normal.  With two dashes, exit immediately.
```